# couchapp: Different rewrites for URLs with and without forward slash

Tags: url-rewriting, couchdb, couchapp

Basically, I want two different rewrite rules for these URLs: http://127.0.0.1:5984/test/_design/myapp/_rewrite/docs/abc
http://127.0.0.1:5984/test/_design/myapp/_rewrite/docs/abc/

The first one will be rewritten as http://127.0.0.1:5984/test/_design/myapp/_show/single/abc while the second one will be rewritten as http://127.0.0.1:5984/test/_design/myapp/_list/container/all

I tried doing this:

```
{
    "---": "Container Retrieval",
    "method": "GET",
    "from": "/docs/*/",
    "to": "/_list/basic-container/all"
  }
```

Both of the URLs (with and without the forward slash) redirect to http://127.0.0.1:5984/test/_design/myapp/_list/container/all. It seems like couchDB ignores the forward slash at the end of the URL.

What are the possible solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The asterisk catches the whole following path. Try the following instead:

```
{
  "method": "GET",
  "from": "/docs/:id",
  "to": "/_show/single/:id"
},
{
  "method": "GET",
  "from": "/docs/:id/",
  "to": "/_list/basic-container/all"
}
```